# How to make a button that can only be clicked once

Tags: vba

In visual basic I'm trying to make a button that can only be clicked once, I want to be able to see the button, its just I want it so you can only click it once.

This is my code so far:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disable the button after they click on it. Then they will not be able to click on it anymore, but it will remain visible. Make sure to disable the button first, especially if your event code is multi-threaded. Otherwise, it may provide the user an opportunity to click on the button again before you want them to.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Button1.Enabled = False
        ' Do something
    End Sub
End Class
```

Another approach if you don't want to disable the button would be to set a global (preferably private) variable to keep track of it.

```
Public Class Form1
    Private button1Clicked As Boolean = False
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If button1Clicked Then
           ' Optionally inform user they've already clicked on it.
           MessageBox.Show("You've already clicked on the button.")
        Else
            button1Clicked = True
            ' Do something
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Or you could use the `Tag` property.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    If Button1.Tag = True Then 
       ' Optionally inform user they've already clicked on it.
       MessageBox.Show("You've already clicked on the button.")
    Else
        Button1.Tag = True
        ' Do something
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   'Do what you need to do here, and then 
   Button1.Enabled = false
End Sub
```

Comment: jajaja, by seconds you answers first